# Hos do I make a Query that results in multiple entries in Table1 that match Multiple entries in Table 2

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, match

I am trying to match Interests of Adopted Kids to the skills of Mentors/ Teachers for an Orphanage.

Table 1 [Students:Table] includes four Student Interests.

Students Table:
Student Name
{Other Student Data}
Interest 1
Interest 2
Interest 3
Interest 4

Table 2 [Mentors:Table] has six Mentor Skills:
Mentor Name
{Other Mentor Data}
Skill 1
Skill 2
Skill 3
Skill 4
Skill 5
Skill 6

[Skills] and [Interests] comes from the same Table of 100 Interests / Skills so assume they are numerical and identical if they exist.

How do I create a Query that gives me a result of every instance where Interest 1, 2, 3, OR 4 matches Skills 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, OR 6

The Query result would be something like:

[Student Mentor Match:Query]
Sally J. - Mr. Thomas - Interest/Skill 4
Sally J. - Ms. Smith - Interest/Skill 38
Suzy L.  - Mr. Bennett - Interest/Skill 22
etc.

Comment: Have you heard of `JOIN` in SQL? And please format your question for readability.

Comment: Yes, and when I JOIN Interest 1 to Skill 1, I get the correct results for a Match between those two areas.  When I try to JOIN anything else, i.e., Interest 1 to Skill 1 as one JOIN and Interest 2 to Skill 2 as another JOIN in the same query, I lose the results of the first JOIN and continue to get no results.  Mathematically, I would need the following JOINs: 1 to 1; 1 to 2; 1 to 3; 1 to 4; 1 to 5; 1 to 6; 2 to 1; 2 to 2; etc. etc. 4 to 4; 4 to 5; and 4 to 6; for 24 JOINS to answer, "Do any of the 4 Student Interests match any of the 6 Mentor Skills?"  I cannot figure this out using JOINs.

Comment: Please edit your post to show attempted query, current results, and desired results and not in comments.